# (Apology) Dear Moderators (Doktor Mayhem, Dom, and Matthew Read),

Tags: discussion, support

This is Maika Sakuranomiya, an established user in Music Stack Exchange.  I would like to apologize for my bad behavior.

I've signed up as a user here last Autumn, and I've been constantly violating rules - the four major cases included so far:

1. Posted a large amount of low-quality answers, and one of them contained plagiarized content - Penalty: I've received a warning note by a moderator: *"We take plagiarism **very seriously** on Stack Exchange.  Please be aware."*
2. Created a sockpuppet account to artificially increase my reputation score - Penalty: I was suspended for a week: *"This account is **temporarily suspended** for voting irregularities."*
3. Asked a lot of questions that were not well-received by the community - Penalty: Another suspension for a week: *"This account is **temporarily suspended** because of low-quality contributions."*
4. Made an excessive amount of trivial edits to my posts as an anonymous user - Penalty: I have been suspended for a month (!) : *"This account is **temporarily suspended** for rule violations."*

I understand the rules, and I'll promise there will be no more rule violations from now on.

---

After the fourth event, I've returned here and began posting various well-received posts about modal cadences.  For one of them, I've even earned a bounty worth 100 reputation and my reputation score was boosted up high.

---

So, I would like to apologize to you guys, and I'll try my best to show my best behavior from now on.  I also would like you guys to give me some tips for the best ways of high-quality contributions, please.  Thank you!

---

Sincerely,

Maika Sakuranomiya

Comment: Good to hear you're sticking around! :)

Comment: Even though I'm not a moderator, I really appreciate your willingness to change your interaction. This site only lives because of users, so we always want more users who are participating fully, changing into one of those users is the best thing you could do for the site, so on behalf of all the other users: **THANK YOU!**

Comment: Thank you for being so candid, and I hope you stay with our site and contribute to it.

Comment: Just so you're aware; there's very little record of the actions written in 1 (only to users with 20k+ reputation) and precisely no public record of 2–4. I'm sure nobody will mind if you delete this meta question a bit later.

Comment: This didn't age well. LOL.

Answer (score 4):

### It is deeply disturbing to me that ~two months after this apology, this user was suspended for a full year - the maximum suspension duration.

I commend an honest apology effort, and obviously I don't know why the suspension was invoked (I wasn't actually active on the site when it occurred), but it chills me to realise that what was initially a gesture of apology now stands in stark contrast to this user's perigee.

The other remarkable thing is that *this was the maximum suspension length.* If the problems continue, what will be next? I'm aware that the community has at least a year to figure this out, but I am not optimistic about this in the least.

I just found a bit of a [cross-site dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332685/401908) that I think's worth a read.

Comment: I dont get this. Did he get suspended because the actions he apologised for or did he violate the rules again after his apologise?

Comment: @Olli I'm not in charge of the suspension, and as such, I do not know which incident earned the user the suspension. Either option is possible. All I know is that this question post was followed by another suspension two months later.

Comment: I cannot go into specifics, but it was not due to the apology and due to several new offenses some of which are based on a previous reason for suspension.

Comment: There's a little more clarity why maika is suspended here on meta SE with some mod messages included: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337396/how-do-moderators-decide-how-long-to-suspend-users-for