# Why was this a "trivial edit" when I was trying to make the title more explicit?

Tags: support, editing

https://music.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/70806

And what can I do instead? What constitutes a "trivial edit"?

Comment: [This Meta.SE thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74430/why-are-trivial-edits-discouraged) may be helpful.

Comment: I found the edit very helpful and have made many similar edits myself. I can't imagine why it was rejected, aside from, maybe, an error on the voter's part.

Comment: @Aaron one word: Maika

Comment: @Dom I don't know what that means. Is this an issue for a private chat?

Comment: @Aaron see https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3324/apology-dear-moderators-doktor-mayhem-dom-and-matthew-read for a start

Comment: @Dom Troublesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maika, we've been over this many times, but I'll state it 1 more time to be crystal clear:

If you are editing just to bump your content, they will never be allowed. This is the same pattern that got you suspended and I'm not sure why you are highlighting it.

I'd also say in general replacing terms in a title with an acronym makes it less searchable and using the terms the OP never used makes it slightly confusing which is another reason why the rollback would have made sense.  The title "Can a VII-i in a minor key still be considered an imperfect authentic cadence?" could have been acceptable, but again **if you are using it to bump your content, it is still not acceptable**.

If you want to help make other posts and titles be more clear please feel free to, but please **do not try to continue to bump your own posts**.

Comment: Thanks, but - 1. I had no intention of bumping my own posts at all. / 2. A leading-tone IAC already IS a real concept (although VII-i doesn't really use the leading-tone). / 3. I just made another edit request based on your suggestion in your 3rd paragraph.

Comment: @HonokaKousaka you literally did not read any of this post. You have a history of bumping your own posts. I did not say a leading tone IAC is not a real concept, I said the poster did not use those terms and again because of your history, any small edits on posts you contribute to including the question itself that haven't been active in a while will be taken as bad faith actions due to __your past history__. I cannot explain this any clearer.